# c# overload generic functions with different parameter constraints

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

I have the following functions:

```
public static V AddIfNotPresent<K, V>( this Dictionary<K, V> store, K key ) where V : new()

public static V AddIfNotPresent<K, V>( this Dictionary<K, V> store, K key )
```

First off... is it possible to overload the functions in this way?

If overloading is not possible could I be more specific with my functions and implements say:

```
public static string Foo<K, string>( this Dictionary<K, string> store, K key )
```

As a little History I have a Dictionary with string values and I'd live a consistent 'Foo' extension of the Dictionary to allow me to add new() objects or an empty string (as appropriate).

Comment: `Foo<K, string>` is unnecessary because it's already a string, you don't need a second generic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't overload by type parameter constraints. But yes, you *can* overload by the number of type parameters:

```
public static string Foo<TKey>(this Dictionary<TKey, string> store, TKey key)
```

(Note that `string` isn't in the generic type parameters list for Foo; it's not a type parameter itself, it's just used as a type *argument* for `Dictionary`.)